# Responsive css menu disappears if clicked

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i tried to create a Responsive Menu with css.

It react almost properly with different resolutions. But one thing.

If the menu is in wide mode and an href got clicked, the menu disappears and appears realy quick and nothing is happend. The href is not working.

I put my code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/za1yduqv/

If you click the menu multiple times you can see what i mean.

HTML

```
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><div class="nav-sep"></div><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><div class="nav-sep"></div><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><div class="nav-sep"></div><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                <li><div class="nav-sep"></div><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><div class="nav-sep"></div></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
/* ==============
    MOBILE: Menu
   ============== */

#menu-icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(img/menu-icon.png);
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    top: 95px;
    z-index:2;  
}

a:hover#menu-icon {
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

nav ul, nav:active ul  { 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    top: 106px;
    color:#000;
    width: 120px;
    z-index:3;
    font-size:14pt;
    background-image: url("img/nav-pattern.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover  {
    color:#d48c3b;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {

/* ====================
    WIDE: Nav
   ==================== */

    #menu-icon {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-sep {
        background-image: url('img/nav-sep.png');
        width:7px;
        height:30px;
        float:left;
    }

    nav {
        position:absolute;
        right:10px;
        top: 98px;
    }

    nav a {
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size:13.5pt;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 30px;
    }   

    nav ul {
        position: static;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width:100%;
    }

    nav li:last-child a {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    /* ========================
    INTERMEDIATE: IE Fixes
   ======================== */

    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
    }

    .oldie nav a {
        margin: 0 0.7%;
    }

}
```

If you need more code, let me know.

Thanks for reading!
Daniel

Comment: take a look at `a:active`

Answer (score 2):

Add this line:

```css
nav:active ul {display: block;}
```

In your `:active`, it has a `display: none;` that makes the menu disappear!

---

**Update:** You can use something else better than to meddle with this! :(

Comment: Ok, but if i remove it, its still blinking. And if i add your code its also still blinking and the mobile "menu/style" appears. I don't get it... http://jsfiddle.net/za1yduqv/

Comment: Is it not simpler to just remove the display rule in his active effect, rather than create an entirely new rule just to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar What do you mean? What else can i use?

Comment: @egolive There are a lot of responsive menu scripts out there. This looks really screwed.

Comment: Ok mabey you're right. I will have a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get it from blinking the way it does, in your :active rule, remove the `display:none`, and change the absolute to relative that stops the blinking effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/za1yduqv/

Comment: If i remove it, its still blinking and also the mobile "menu/style" appears.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell you to change the position rule.

Comment: Ok, now it's not blinking, but the whole menu moves left and the mobile menu appears. :D Also the hrefs still not working. There is something really wrong :/

Comment: The hrefs aren't working because you don't have them linking to anything.  The mobile menu appears because you're not telling the css what to do with the mobile menu when the screen size is over 640px.  To the stylesheet, that menu is going to appear at all times, the only reason it's not initially is because it's being overlapped by the wide menu, when it moves left, it gives it enough space to show up.

Comment: Ok i will check this. But in my Wordpress Blog where i use this code, i have real links. And with them it's not working. Sorry, could not know it.

Comment: Make sure the paths are correct.  Changing the CSS rules would not have broken the links, so chances are, they weren't working in the first place.  As Praveen mentioned(and I'm not saying this to be rude) your CSS is all over the place and screwed.  Try keeping similar elements together, write the rules for your parent elements first and then write the ones for the children elements and so forth.  Also, looking at your CSS, it seems as though you only designed for mobile, not for desktop, this is not good practice.  If your site is going to be cross platform, you need to design for everything.

Comment: No worries, i know my css is bad. I let it be and will use a ready script. No, i designed it crossover. I just removed the menu part and edit it for you guys. Actually the Menu disappears with 786px.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Using a script is honestly the best way to go when doing something like this.  CSS wasn't really designed to have this kind of functionality to it.  Good luck with getting it working.